# Eclipse SWT List Widget not redrawing until window unfocussed on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, widget, swt

I've created a simple SWT application that has two List widgets.

On the left are some values to choose from in a list.
When you double click on one of them, it is added to the list on the right.

On Windows, this works fine.
But when I try it on Mac, I find that the list on the right only updates once the application has been defocused.

I can't figure out why this be?

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class ListWidgetRefreshTest {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
    new Dialog((Shell) null) {
        @Override
        protected Control createDialogArea(final Composite parent) {
        final Composite composite = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);

        // Create layout
        // Two column layout
        composite.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

        final Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.FILL);
        container.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

        final Composite leftRightPanel = new Composite(container, SWT.FILL);
        leftRightPanel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 2, 1));

        final GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, true);
        layout.marginHeight = 0;
        layout.marginWidth = 0;

        leftRightPanel.setLayout(layout);

        // Add items
        // Left side
        Composite panel = new Composite(leftRightPanel, SWT.FILL);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
        final List leftList = new List(panel, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 3).mapToObj(String::valueOf).forEach(leftList::add);
        // Right side
        panel = new Composite(leftRightPanel, SWT.FILL);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
        final List rightList = new List(panel, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL);

        leftList.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDoubleClick(final MouseEvent e) {
            for (final String selection : leftList.getSelection()) {
                rightList.add(selection);
            }
            }
        });

        return composite;
        }
    }.open();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using joda time?

Comment: Calling `rightList.redraw();` after the `rightList.add` fixes it but it should not be necessary. Are you running this from within Eclipse? I have seen issues on macOS where this happens when run from within Eclipse but not when run as a standalone app.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks - I can't confirm if it happens outside of Eclipse, but your workaround works for me.